# python maya check selected items

Tags: python, maya

How can I check to the selected items in the variable 'curSel' to test whether they are 'vertices' are not. I'm assuming I would use an if/then statement. So then I can remove any further errors.

I'm guessing I could just test to see if the first item in the list is a vert. If it's a vert then proceed and if not then don't do anything. But how would I write this?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# collect the selected verts
curSel = cmds.ls(sl=1, fl=1)
```

Working code: Creates locators for each selected vert

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selectedVerts = [v for v in cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True) if '.vtx' in v]

print selectedVerts

for v in selectedVerts:
    pos = cmds.xform( v, query=True, translation=True, worldSpace=True )
    cmds.spaceLocator( p=(pos) )
```

Comment: How do you want to proceed if the selection includes some vertices and some other types?'

Comment: I would prefer that it only proceed if all the items are vertices. Otherwise it just prints 'select vertices only'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat using the filteExpand command instead of ls.  FilterExpand without arguments always works on the current selection, and the selectionMask option limits it to a particular component type. So

```
cmds.filterExpand(sm=31)
```

will return only the selected vertices and nothing else.  If there aren't any verts selected it will return None.

The other way is just to check the selection for the string '.vtx' which is what you'd get from selected verts

```
selected_verts = [v for v in cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True) if '.vtx' in v]
```

---

Comment: Great work Steve. Thank you. For the sake of knowing. Say a user is in object mode and there are vertices selected on the vertex level. Is there a way to collect those verts even though the use may not currently be in vertex mode?

Comment: both of these will work on the actual selection, so they'll ignore the mode settings in the UI as far as I know.

Comment: I tested it out and it returns 'none'

Comment: Check the working code above. It will not make locators if the user is not actively in sub-object mode.

Comment: Are the verts visibly selected? Maya won't retain the vert selection if you hop in and out of object mode - if you check the standard ls(sl=True) you'll see the change

Comment: I go into Vertex mode - select some verts, then go to object mode. When i revisit the Vertex mode it still maintains the previously selected verts. Is there not a way to get to them?

side note, is there a way to run this command without changing the selection to select the newly created locator? cmds.spaceLocator(name='Donuts', p=(0,0,0,))

Comment: the selection is remembered but not active (try ls(sl=True) after each step)  
if you add select(cl=True) after the locator command it will deselect